# Facebook Messenger - postback outages?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have been successfully developing Facebook Messenger bots for the past couple months and lately have been experiencing an issue where 'postbacks' are sometimes not sent to my server, even though plain typed messages are sent immediately and of course web hooks validate fine.

Sometimes with enough teardown/subscribing of web hooks and pages the postbacks work again but I can't always get it to work again. I have multiple bots and multiple pages running not sure if that is related.

Also, yes I'm currently subscribed to receive postbacks.

Has anyone else experienced this? Thank you

Comment: For me I didn't encounter this condition. Try leave a comment to Facebook? maybe someone there can check for you.

Comment: Thanks @iownthegame where is the best place to direct this question to Facebook?

Comment: try https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Experiencing the same issue over here. It appears that about 50% of the times the postbacks don't make it to our server.

Answer (score 2):

It may have been resolved by now, but i was finally able to figure out when does postback work, and when it does not.

As per my observation, and many tests I came to conclusion, that facebook uses the same access token to "postback" which is used to create the persistant menu, generic template button, or a button template.

If the page Id, or the APP id (which is more probable, as people have a prod and test app for the same bot) differs, the postbacks are not sent back to webhook even though the webhook has the "messaging_postbacks" subscribed.

In my case it turned out the the page access token was generated with the production APP id, and i was testing in my test app, which had different app iD. Also, my persistent menu also worked when generated thru a test app access_token.

As a best practice, i hard code the access token (safer as well, as the generated access_tokens expires in some time) if the environment is not prod, and use the logic to generate the token when the app is live.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot. It took some time to finally figure it out!!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

So it turns out after 44 hours of firefighting, the problem auto-corrected itself. Facebook team replied that all they have is a 502 error. and that too resolved automatically. I have contacted my domain provider and AWS and they said that that the issue is not at their end.

My conclusion, something must be happening in facebook's infrastructure as the same domain cannot have partial 502 errors (meaning for one use case it happens and other it doesn't when the webhook url is same). Hopefully, they figure it out even though they don't tell us.

---

So I don't have any reputation points for commenting so I am posting as an answer. I am facing a similar issue, the only difference is we are getting a quick response in postbacks but not messages.

We are consistently facing a problem of irregular incoming messages on our server for messenger bot. Our observation is that we receive a payload only after a few (random) seconds after the message has been typed (and sent) by the user. However, facebook instantaneously sends us the necessary payload if a buttontap is performed.

We have established that the apache server is not receiving any request (during that time). We have also established that our SSL certificate is not expired. Moreover, we have all the necessary ports open on our AWS instance (mainly 443 and 80).

Any clues anyone? we are facing this issue for last 21-22 hours.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it's great to know I'm not the only one experiencing connectivity issues

Comment: Any updates since then, I am recently facing same issue. For a while I would stop receiving postback payloads but I do get text message payload from Facebook.

Comment: @SagarGalande Sorry I didn't login for a while. Last time it was an issue at facebook side which they repaired over time (probably because it was a new system). You might have found the reason for yours. It would be great if you can post your solution here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This was again on the Facebook side.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem yesterday, while developing the second facebook messenger bot (for the second Page). The postback wont come after some hours, that's what ridiculous (as I expected, the messages shouldn't come!!!).

The reason was the Page Access Token for the second Page was wrong! You have to pick the right Token from the right App. Because it's possible to generate the Page Access Token for the second Page from the first App.

Comment: Thank to my own answer :) I got today again the same problem with postbacks, that they don't come! To be checked were the AppSecret and PageToken!

Answer (score 0):

While subscribing to webhook select messaging_postbacks checkbox.